# Wiener filter yielding negative MSE (and MMSE)

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, finite-impulse-response, statistics, adaptive-filters

I implement a Wiener filter using the following code

```
function [h, yy, mse] = wiener_h(y,x,M)
yy=xcorr(y(1:M));
yy=toeplitz(yy((length(yy)+1)/2:((length(yy)+1)/2)+M-1));
debug = sprintf('Inverting Autocorrelation matrix..')
yy=inv(yy);
%%
debug = sprintf('Crosscorrelation vector')
yx = xcorr(y,x);
yx = yx((length(yx)+1)/2:((length(yx)+1)/2)+M-1); %consider only non-negative lags
debug = sprintf('Optimal Weiner impulse response..')
h =yy*yx;
mmse = var(x)-h'*yy*h;
mse = var(x)-2*yx'*h+h'*yy*h;
```

where `y` is the input signal, `x` the desired output, `M` number of coefficients, `h` the optimal (wiener  values) and `mse` the mean square error.
The input to the filter is are magnitude values of a pulse (NR, SV, SA)
The desired output is TX
[image]
The output of

```
[h, yy, mse] = wiener_h(y,x,15000)
plot(t,filter(h,1,y))
```

where the number of coefficients M is equal to the number of samples N, is `mse = -1.14e+03`
Whereas the output of

```
 [h, yy, mse] = wiener_h(y,x,1500)
 plot(t,filter(h,1,y))
```

Where the number of coefficients is 10% of N, is `mse = -7.68e+04`
The plotted results of the two above (left M=N, right M=0.1N)

Can someone help me understand what's going on please?
[image]

Comment: there is no **jm** in the code, as you mentioned its name?

Comment: sorry, edited to correct couple of distractions